# How to increase size of GUI/font/everything of Oracle SQL Developer 18.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I downloaded Windows 64-bit with JDK 8 included of SQL Developer 18.1.

To run Oracle SQL Developed I just unzipped the file and run the sqldeveloper.exe contained in the folder.

Unfortunately, as you can see in the image the size of everything is extremely small and very difficult to see.[image]

This issue appears exclusively with this software.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

I guess this is a subjective statement - but that doesn't appear SMALL to me.

However, if you're using an OS accessibility feature to increase the size of text in your applications, the new 'Welcome Page' can interfere with that.

Uncheck 'show on startup' in the Welcome page

[image]

Restart SQL Developer.

You should be good.

The Welcome page uses JavaFX to render some HTML and this is apparently getting in the way due to a Java bug. We're looking to mitigate or fix this for a future release.

---

If that doesn't work, you can also try to actually increase the UI font size.

I talk about how to do that [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/12/how-to-change-the-ui-font-size-for-oracle-sql-developer/)

This is what it looks like bumped up to font size 14

Find your ide.properties file.

**Windows**: It's in your OS User's AppData, Roaming, SQL Developer, system*X.Y.Z*..., o.sqldeveloper directory where X.Y.Z... represents your version of SQL Developer.

**Linux/Mac**: It's in your $HOME/.sqldeveloper, systemX.Y.Z, o.sqldeveloper directory.

You’ll notice this file is VERY well documented. There’s a section that speaks to Windows in particular. To change the default size for all look and feels, add this line, the uncommented one:

```
# To modify the font size for a particular locale under all
# look-and-feels, set the Ide.FontSize.<languageID> property. For
# example:
Ide.FontSize.en=14
```

Make sure SQL Developer is closed as you save ide.properties. Since SQL Developer writes to the ide.properties every time its closed that will overwrite the settings you saved.

[image]

**2018 Update**

On my 4k Mac Mini (2018 build if that matters):

- Oracle 8 JDK
- SQL Developer 18.3
- Mac OS X look and feel
- Ide.FontSize=21

This is how SQL Developer looks:

[image]

Comment: I don't have any show on startup.
I saw some documentation talking about the IDE.properties file but since I am running an .exe, there is no installation so I cannot find that file anywhere

Comment: Switch to 'Welcome Page'. Now scroll down to the VERY bottom, and look at the left hand side of the document. It's there.

Comment: As for IDE.properties, if you click on the link I shared, i show you in detail how to find the conf files

Comment: Do you have any idea why this issue happened to me and not to all my colleagues?

Comment: @Seymour are you running any OS based accessibility features, like magnification of text? Do you have a 4k monitor? And more importantly, did my answer actually address your issue? If you're on a 4k monitor, you might want to try Java 9

Comment: in the end I found the Ide.config file and modify it. Also I Unchecked 'show on startup' in the Welcome page. Therefore, I do not know which one of these actually solved the issue. Thank you very much

Comment: I have to re-open the question. This solution **only** change the text size in the table view. It does not affect icons or any other text in SQL Developer

Comment: it won't affect icons, it will affect the UI text as shown in my screenshot @Seymour

Comment: how can I increase the size of everything?

Comment: Use your OS accessibility settings and use the Windows or OS X Look and feel a la https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/08/look-and-feel-feel-free-to-go-crazy/

Comment: Make sure SQL Developer is closed while you edit `ide.properties`. SQL Developer writes to `ide.properties` every time its closed, which confuses most editors.

Comment: The path to ide.properties is C:\Users\your Name\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system19.1.0.094.2042\o.sqldeveloper, once I uncommented and changed Ide.FontSize=14, the UI font looks bigger. Thanks!

Comment: This solution does fix it. However, it has been so long since the answer was posted. I just downloaded the latest version of SQL Developer (Version 19.2.1.247) and this issue is still present. Pity that an issue that's staring right in your face has not been fixed for so long.

Comment: @knp it's a Java problem... Tableau has similar issues

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! The path to ide.properties was this for me (for some reason Windows search was not finding it...): C:\Users\<myUser>\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system19.4.0.354.1759\o.sqldeveloper.19.3.0.354.1759

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution

Comment: @thatjeffsmith, thank you. this works. but how to set the font face e.g. Times New Roman?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Too bad you didn't work at Oracle so you could get this bug fixed...its been over 2 years and it is still present.

Comment: I think we'll have a 'fix' for next update, stay tuned

Comment: has nothing to do with any of IDE settings, called Jugaad :)

Comment: Unchecking 'show on startup' in the Welcome page, gave me the desired result.

Comment: What a amaze, only unchecking open 'Welcome Page' on startup resolved my issue

Comment: Thanks, this solution works to me, I uncheked  'show on startup' in Welcome page.

Answer (score 141):

I also faced a similar issue when installed this on Windows 10. The issue has to do with compatibility settings.

I have fixed it following the steps given below:

1. Get shortcut of `sqldeveloper` at your desktop
2. Ensure that you have admin rights in your PC
3. Right Click on `sqldeveloper` icon and select *Properties*.
4. Go to the **Compatibility tab**:

   - Compatibility mode change it to windows 7
   - Check the option of Override high DPI scaling beaviour
   - Select "System" in drop down below
5. Apply
6. Re-Launch the application

Comment: For me it worked by these steps... SQL Dev Shortcut -> Compatibility - > Change high DPI settings -> Override high DPI scaling behavior (Checked)-> Re-Launch Program. I did not find 'Compatibility mode change it to windows 7.'

Comment: in Linux just change ~/.sqldeveloper/system18.3.0.277.2354/o.sqldeveloper/ide.properties  Ide.FontSize

Comment: It worked for me, you can skip the create shortcut step, directly change the compatibility mode of the sqldeveloper.exe is also possible. Thank you.

Comment: I had to select "System (Enhanced)" on Windows 10, otherwise worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks ! its worked for me also . Open Property  by right clicking on launcher icon --->Compatibility - --> Change high DPI settings ->System   apply and relaunch

Comment: In linux, with 4k display increasing FontSize doesn't work, font will overlap and we cannot read it properly.

So change DPI setting:
open sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf
add ' AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2 ' at end of the file.
It works fine

Comment: You saved Sprint-Demo-Day!  Me and my Progressive Lens thank you.

Comment: Here is a link with screenshots on how to do this. http://christian-gohmann.de/2018/10/25/running-sql-developer-on-high-dpi-screens

Comment: At this point, I have to wonder whether this software goes through QA at all. The issue literally stares at them the moment you start the application

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me even I have MS window 10.

Comment: worked for me without shortcut to desktop step

Answer (score 15):

I changed font style and size from available settings from SQL developer.
We can change using Tools -> Preferences ->Code Editor -> Fonts

[image: SQL developer settings]

Answer (score 12):

Fixed this for myself in Oracle Linux 8, but is also worth trying in RHEL and Fedora, if you use either of those.

If SQL Developer is running, close it.

With superuser privileges, open the following file for editing:

```
sudo nano /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf
```

Add the following two lines at the end:

```
AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=2
AddVMOption -Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=true
```

Restart SQL Developer.

If the interface still looks too small, or too big, change the uiScale value (untested).

Comment: This did not work on Ubuntu 20.04 running sqldeveloper 21.2 with Oracle Java 11

Comment: this actually did work for me, thanks
Ubuntu 20.04.3  openjdk-11  sqldeveloper 21.4.1.349

Comment: This worked for me with Ubuntu running Sql Developer 17. I used ....uiScale=3 for with my 4k monitor and aging eyes. Everything is a little too big at 3 but too small at 2 and you can't use decimals, just integers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue,
if you still could not fix the problem with the given solutions, for me also worked the following:

Go to the **Display Settings**;

Go to **scaling and "reset it"**: change to another scale, for example, 100% and then to your preferred scale;

This should force the SQL-Developer Window to your preferred scale, unfortunately you have to repeat this procedure after every new SQL-Developer launch.

Comment: Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

change the setting from "Compatibility tab" as highlighted in the above post was the only way to make the icon much more larger

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone landed here looking for the same answer for a newer version of Oracle SQL Developer (like I did)…

As of v22.2.1, for macOS the preferences are now located in **Oracle SQL Developer** --> Settings…

[image: Oracle SQL Developer menu]

You can adjust the font style and size under Code Editor --> Fonts

[image: Oracle SQL Developer preferences pane]

Hope that helps!